# Play Framework + Intellij: Super slow compilation times

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to fix the horrible slow compile times of Play and Scala.
It compiles constantly hudrends of java classes.
Has anyone faced this and solved it?

Thanks

Comment: SBT is just slow by nature. There's a reason why it is nicknamed "Slow Build Tool"... In all seriousness, I would recommend splitting up your (presumably monolith) service into a few microservices and running them all on different ports (eg `sbt "run 9053"`, `sbt "run 8080"`, etc). It will speed up compile time for at least some of them, and is probably best practice at this point as abstracting different functionality can be very useful when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed completely the **enhancer plugin**, and the compilation times are now normal.
**IMO this is a huge issue of the play framework.** 
I got the idea from [this post](https://medium.com/@jfcote/the-ultimate-solution-to-play-framework-slow-compilation-53f4fd499df4), however I did not simply disable the plugin and I did not create any getters and setters. I only commented out the plugin locally. When the app is deployed the plugin is there generating the setters and getters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application with sbt-run, or run as play application in paid version of intellij, instead of running NettyServer or ProdServerStart, then play will use multiple class loaders to only recompile modified files instead of all classes.

Comment: then, create a run configuration as sbt task, and use "run", as task. Or just type "sbt run" in terminal.

Comment: I've already done that. The problem is that it takes too long to compile (5-10 
 minutes or more). I'm looking for a 'magic' option somewhere that will make this go away. At the moment it's a huge problem for me.I have worked with e clispe on *really* huge projects (no sbt) and it was super fast. (Even during debugging hot swap was instant)

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with one of your dependencies. Try deleting all files in .ivi2/cache  . (Or if you find that compilation gets stuck in one speceific dependency, just delete that)